# Group and count data based on a calculated field in mysql?

Tags: mysql, group-by, field

I have 2 tables in mysql that record the dates a certain event happens.

- Table 1: (id, session_id, date)
- Table 2: (id, session_date)

Table1 is the main table where I only write either session_id (in that case the date is fetched from Table2's matching record) or date. The field that I'm not filling, stays NULL.

Now, I want to count how many times that event has happened per month/year and, if possible, only do that procedure after a specific date (e.g. 01-01-2013).

Here's what I've done so far, I've created another date field (called date_final) that holds the non-NULL value per row, so I'm trying to group my data based on that field.

```
SELECT table1.date AS date1, 
       table2.session_date AS date2, 
       @date_final := CONCAT_WS('', table1.date, table2.session_date) AS date_final,
       MONTHNAME(@date_final) AS `month`,
       YEAR(@date_final) AS `year`   
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.session_id
GROUP BY YEAR(@date_final), MONTH(@date_final)
```

Obviously this has not worked very well, hence I'm here. MySQL returns to me only some values per month/year and that's not good. It gets even worse when I add the COUNT(*) clause. I'm just a newbie in mysql and I guess I'm getting into deep waters here :P

```
##Sample data for Table1##
#id  session_id  date#
1            1  NULL
2         NULL  2013-01-04
3            2  NULL
4         NULL  2013-01-20
5         NULL  2013-02-22
6            3  NULL

##Sample data for Table2##
#id  session_date#
1       2013-01-02
2       2013-01-10
3       2013-03-02
```

Expected results? Something like:

```
2013  January  3
2013  February 2
2013  March    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the session variable since the rules of using them reliably aren't straight forward, what you seem to be looking for is a `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE`, something like;

```sql
SELECT 
  YEAR(COALESCE(table1.date, table2.session_date)) year,
  MONTHNAME(COALESCE(table1.date, table2.session_date)) month,
  COUNT(*) cnt
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.session_id = table2.id
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY year, MONTH(COALESCE(table1.date, table2.session_date))
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d0f8/2).

Note that here `table1.date` takes precedence over `table2.session_date`, if you want it the other way you'll have to reverse the order in the `COALESCE`s.

Comment: Just wondering though, where can I fit a 'where' clause so that I only get dates after a specific one (e.g. after 01-02-2013)

Comment: @Gorrister If I'm understanding correctly how you want to filter, you can put something like `WHERE COALESCE(table1.date, table2.session_date) >= '2013-02-01'
` just before the `GROUP BY` line.

Answer (score 1):

One possibly is that you intend:

```
SELECT table1.date AS date1, 
       table2.session_date AS date2, 
       coalesce(table1.date, table2.session_date) AS date_final,
       MONTHNAME(coalesce(table1.date, table2.session_date)) AS `month`,
       YEAR(coalesce(table1.date, table2.session_date)) AS `year`   
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN
     table2
     ON table2.id = table1.session_id
GROUP BY MONTHNAME(coalesce(table1.date, table2.session_date)),
         YEAR(coalesce(table1.date, table2.session_date))
order by `month`, `year`;
```

You don't need a session variable for this.

Comment: This pretty much gives the same results as my query :(